# Extruded area is not filled

Tags: mesh, extrude, wireframe

I have a single sketch with multiple vertices and faces. Once I select one face, and press `A` to select all faces and extrude, the extrusion happens but the volume in between is not filled. The reference photos are attached:

[image: All faces selected]
[image: After extrusion]

Answer (score 2):

Your mesh has been extruded already. I mean, you pressed <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude then canceled the operation, but when you cancel "extrude and move" you cancel only "move", but not "extrude". So you have 2 copies of vertexes that exactly overlap each other.

Simplest way to fix this - select all, then press <kbd>M</kbd> -> By distance. It will remove overlapping vertexes and only clean geometry will be left